# Get an error when deploying a Stripe application on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, vercel, next.js13

I have a Next.js V.13.4 application that implements the payment method Stripe. Everything works locally without problems and without errors. However, when I try to load the app on Vercel, I get the error below in the logs.
Since I use Next in version 13.4, I also use the route handler. That means that I have the CheckoutForm-page outside of the api folder. app/CheckoutForm/page.tsx

app/StripeSite/page.tsx:

```
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CheckoutForm from "../CheckoutForm/page";

return (
<>
  {clientSecret && (
    <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
      <div className=" flex flex-grow justify-center border p-4 m-8 w-auto">
        <CheckoutForm />
      </div>
    </Elements>
  )}
 </>
);
```

Error on Vercel:

> Failed to pre-render page "/CheckoutForm". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
> Error: The elements context could not be found. You must wrap the part of your app that calls useStripe() in an  provider.